# angularJS ng repeat field and special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to display all of the batters and their stats on my team from a json file into a table using angularjs.

HTML:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="players">
      <tr ng-repeat="x in player | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{x.player_name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.components.B_OBP}}</td>
        <td>{{x.components.B_K%}}</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

JS:

```
var baseballApp = angular.module('baseballApp', []);

baseballApp.controller('Players', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = 'Players';
    $http.get('http://example.com/myteam.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.player = response.data;
    });
});
```

JSON:

```
{

    "player_name": "Mookie Betts",
    "positions": {
        "PR": 0,
        "LF": 0,
        "C": 0,
        "DH": 0,
        "SS": 0,
        "CF": 0,
        "P": 0,
        "RF": 53,
        "1B": 0,
        "2B": 0,
        "3B": 0,
        "PH": 0
    },
    "handedness": {
        "bats": "R",
        "throws": "R"
    },
    "player_type": "b",
    "components": {
        "B_OPS": ".882",
        "B_SLG": ".516",
        "B_BSR": "3.6",
        "B_TEAM": "",
        "B_PA": "643",
        "B_3B": "4",
        "B_RBI": "94",
        "B_AB": "581",
        "B_R": "95",
        "B_2B": "38",
        "B_BB": "51",
        "B_ISO": ".206",
        "B_UBR": "3.5",
        "B_WOBA": ".375",
        "B_GDP": "",
        "B_H": "180",
        "B_SEASON": "2017",
        "B_SO": "71",
        "B_SH": "3",
        "B_WGDP": "",
        "B_SPD": "5.5",
        "B_SF": "5",
        "B_IBB": "1",
        "B_SB": "21",
        "B_G": "145",
        "B_WSB": "0.1",
        "B_BB/K": "0.72",
        "B_AVG": ".310",
        "B_CS": "9",
        "B_OFF": "28.4",
        "B_WRC+": "132",
        "B_HR": "25",
        "B_K%": "0.111",
        "B_WAR": "5.6",
        "B_BB%": "0.08",
        "B_BABIP": ".317",
        "B_1B": "113",
        "B_HBP": "3",
        "B_WRAA": "30.2",
        "B_WRC": "106",
        "B_DEF": "4.1",
        "B_OBP": ".366"
    },
    "player_id": "13611"

},
```

I am able to show most stats correctly until i get to a stat with a special character such as B_K% or B_WRC+

I keep on receiving this error:

```
Unexpected end of expression: x.components.B_K%
```

Im not totally sure how to escape the character as

```
{{x.components.["B_K%"]}}
```

doesn't seem to help

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `{{x.components["B_K%"]}}`

Comment: WOW! i have been at this all day! Thank you @user2340824, worked like a charm!

Comment: That's no problem at all! Glad to help!